# can i add new Object to cache with existing object as a comma(,) seperator values?

Tags: redis, node-redis

```
        cache data is not retriveing after appending new Object to cache. 

    const redis = require('redis');
    const client = redis.createClient();
    exports.createComplaint = function(req, res, next) {
     sales.create(salesData).then(salesInfo => {
            client.append('my test key',JSON.stringify(salesInfo));
    }
    }





        while getting data:-
        =================================
         client.get('my test key', (err, result1) => {
                if (result1) {
                    console.log('SERVING FROM REDIS CACHE');

                    return res.json({ status: 'success', data: JSON.parse(result1),})

        the data is appending like below without seperation ,i think thats why cache is not returning ??
        Please provide any solution to  get data from redis Cache???

        "{\"id\":70,\"customer_id\":15,\"product_name\":\"mobile\",\"product_type\":\"electronic\",\"maker\":\"lg\",\"model\":\"Pavilion\",\"purchased_from\":\"asian electronics\",\"purchased_date\":\"2019-07-24T10:44:25.311Z\",\"bill_amount\":500}
{\"id\":71,\"customer_id\":15,\"product_name\":\"mobile\",\"product_type\":\"electronic\",\"maker\":\"lg\",\"model\":\"Pavilion\",\"purchased_from\":\"asian electronics\",\"purchased_date\":\"2019-07-24T10:46:23.765Z\",\"bill_amount\":500}"
```

the data is stored in cache like that no (,) comma seperator,I need data dynamically add to cache and get all data in cache while querying

Comment: you might want to consider using RedisJSON see: https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/commands/#jsonarrappend

Comment: but i nedd to get data as a comma seperator  objects.

Comment: you should store each JSON object in a Redis list (by using `rpush`, for example https://redis.io/commands/rpush), and then retrieve the list with `lrange` https://redis.io/commands/lrange). Or if you want to save it in a simple key value string, you'll need to get the key first, parse it as JSON, add to the array, and set it again in the cache.